# Mongoose cant fetch all objects from array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a mongoose query that should fetch all Participants in certain Event model, but I only get back one participant. I tried the `$all` method, still no result.

query:

```
Participants.find({'_id': {$all: event.participants}}, (err, participants) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(participants);
});
```

output:

```
 [ { createdAt: 1970-01-01T00:00:00.011Z,
_id: 5be7fc340016817bcb4ybdfc,
name: 'TEST',
ticket: 5be7fc340016817bc44fbdfb,
email: 'test@test.com',
__v: 0 } ]
```

expected output

```
[ { createdAt: 1970-01-01T00:00:00.011Z,
_id: 5be7fc340016817bcb4fbdfc,
name: 'TEST',
ticket: 5be7fc3400d16817bcb4fbdfb,
email: 'rene370d@gmail.com',
__v: 0 }, 
{ createdAt: 1970-01-01T00:00:00.011Z,
_id: 5be7fc340016817bcb4fbdfc,
name: 'Another test',
ticket: 5be7fc3s40016817bcb4fbdfb,
email: 'another@emai.com',
__v: 0 }  ]
```

event.participants

```
 participants:{
type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
ref: 'ParticipantSchema'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all):

> The $all operator selects the documents where the value of a field is an array that contains all the specified elements.

So it doesn't make much sense to use it to get all documents for a certain model.
Instead, use the `$in` operator

```
Participants.find({ _id: { $in: event.participants } }, (err, participants) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(participants);
});
```

Comment: this code gets all the participants for every event, I only would like to fetch for one certain event